# android application closing programmatically

Tags: android, exit

I am working on an Android project the requirement is if exception occurs in any activity. Then application should exit automatically after the catch block is executed. I am aware Android application architecture doesn't recommend self closing of application.

Comment: try to call `finish()` in every activity in catch block or wherever you want to close your app...

Comment: you need to close the app entirely which mean background itself or you want alive when exception is happen.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to code an application

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

And check out following link for more details [Android App closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974792/how-to-close-an-android-application)
Hope it helps, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Intent intObj=new Intent(this, Home.class);
 intObj.putExtra("finish", true);
 intObj.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
               Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

To terminate your Android application programatically (and gracefully), consider implementing finish-chain mechanism. To be concrete,

#### (1) Implement onResume() of all your Activity subclasses like the following.

```
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    // Check if the application is in the process of
    // stopping. How to implement 'App' in the code
    // below is up to you.
    if (App.getInstance().isStopping())
    {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    ......
```

#### (2) Call the method like below when you want to terminate your application.

```
protected void exit()
{
    // Turn into 'stopping' state.
    App.getInstance().setStopping(true);

    // Finish this Activity. This removes this Activity
    // instance from the Activity stack and the next
    // Activity instance will be displayed. And if the
    // next Activity's onResume() is implemented like the
    // above example, the next Activity will finish(), too.
    // This finish-chain mechanism continues until it
    // reaches the root Activity.
    finish();
}
```

Because Android is likely to reuse the root Activity instance instead of 'new' it, onResume() of the root Activity has to clear 'stopping' flag.

```
protected final void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if (App.getInstance().isStopping())
    {
        // Close this Activity, meaning that this application is closed
        // because this Activity is the root.
        finish();

        // Reset the termination state because Android may reuse this
        // Activity instance instead of creating a new one.
        App.getInstance().setStopping(false);
    }
    else
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

**Sample application which implements 'exit' (and even 'restart') mechanism:**
https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-android-base-sample

**Sample base root Activity:**
https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-android-base/blob/master/src/main/java/com/neovisionaries/android/app/BaseRootActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one activity, you can use finishAffinity for closing all of them

> ```
>  finishAffinity();
> ```