# How to quit android application(along with services) from notification button

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am making a music player app. I made a custom notification with player buttons. While other things are just working fine, I am unable to find on how can I quit application when user presses quit button on the notification.

I tried system.exit() and musicService.stopSelf() but of no use from here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10051799/2263561