# Android Terminate application on-click and back button both in each activity

Tags: android

In my app I have Multiple activities so here I want to terminate entire app In each activity..

on each activity I have options menu so at Options menu I have given this

```
else if (id == R.id.exit) {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);/*finish();
        System.exit(0);*/
    }
```

But its going to main activity

how to terminate entire application on back button pressed twice and on options menu exit..

can any one tell me..

Comment: just keep finishing previous activities as move forward in your app. It will automatically exit when back press

Comment: I want to exit in each activity...

Comment: @Don'tBenegative, do you want to kill individual activity or entire application itself when you click on exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### when you intent activity from splash screen need to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK,FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION

```
  Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, mClass);
   mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    context.startActivity(mIntent);
    finishActivity();
```

1)declare this variable globally

---

```
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

2)Then Implement this 3 below method 
--------------------------------
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();

    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
     Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);

}

 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mHandler != null) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

}

private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Drashti. You can join our gujarai ahmedabad group room here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93330/the-great-gujarati-android-developers-ever

Answer (score 0):

Use this answer:
[How to close an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974792/how-to-close-an-android-application)

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

Comment: here I want to terminate entire application mean all activities at a time

Answer (score 0):

Please add `finish();` method after `startActivity(intent);` method in every activity.

Comment: in splash activity I have already given this `SplashActivity.this.finish();` but still it showing..

Comment: Please also put System.exit(1); 1 is for true and 0 is for false

Comment: I have tried with exit (1) and (0).. ok ...how to terminate on options menu