# force-stop the application programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to `force-stop` an application from my Android app, (Instead of doing manually like `apps-force->stop`). How to achieve this?

I used:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
system.exit(0);
```

It crashes.

Comment: You were used right one. What is the result for that. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5100728/940096)

Comment: i dont think you should do both together. Do either of them

Comment: it also exit from app,is any way to force stop app in programatically....plz tell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force stop my android application programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100728/how-to-force-stop-my-android-application-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` this code is correct and best one. If you need more information Refer link as [How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application) and [Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29).

You can also try this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourCurrentActivity.this, yourNextActivity.class);  
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);  
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

You start an activity, and then close current activity.

Comment: where are you using this code `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`. Are you want to close your application or 3rd party application.

Comment: on last activity , i have give this inside  onclick()

Comment: this code for start home activity , i want to force stop my app

Comment: This code is working for me. Please check.. You start another activity and close current activity.

Comment: I don't want to start a new activity. All I need is to close an application like the manual one do(go to apps-> forcestop). I want it to be done programatically.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this code in your close button and your app will stop

```
private void endapp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

You can try with this one also

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(10);
```

Comment: killing process id not removing app from recent list

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
private void QuitApp() {

    //getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true); //Move the task containing this activity to the back of the activity stack. 

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
    System.exit(0);
  }
```

Comment: This is fundamentally misguided - it is not the job of the app developer to terminate the process, rather they should simply call finish() if its work is concluded.  The system will decide the appropriate process lifetime.