# Android kill process

Tags: android, process, kill

How to kill whole application in onne single click.. finish() is not working?? it redirects to tha previous activity...pls guide me.

```
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WallpaperManager wp = WallpaperManager
                    .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            try {
                Display d = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                        .getDefaultDisplay();
                int width = d.getWidth();
                int height = d.getHeight();
                wp.setBitmap(b1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("error", "Cannot set image as wallpaper", e);
            }

                        finish();

        }
```

Comment: Although people are answering your question you should really look at Gunaseelan's post & read "Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon.

Comment: Sorry,i have tried...but not working

Answer (score 31):

`System.exit()` does not kill your app if you have more than one activity on the stack

Use `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` this way.

for sample

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

For more detail see [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon) , [How to force stop my android application programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100728/how-to-force-stop-my-android-application-programatically/5100808#5100808)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i have two activity.activity one display iamges in gridview and second activity display selected image in fullview.when i click on set wallpaper both activity should b closed na...but it didn;t work by using aby finish,system,exit(0),process kill...

Comment: may be m wrong..but i write finish in both activity after working.. now its working fine :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this function to close your application

```
Process.killProcess( Process.myPid() );
```

Comment: int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
                 android.os.Process.killProcess(pid); i wrote this command..but it didn't work for me... it just kill the current activity

Answer (score 1):

- Use `startActivityForResult` to start any activity.
- Write `finish()` in `onActivityResult` of the activity in which you are starting another activity if `result == RESULT_CANCELLED`.
- Finally use `finish()` at the point of exit.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Finish ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Added in API level 1
Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The Activity Result is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().

you must use System.exit() to kill your application on a click to directly close the activity.

> Why finish() is not working for you ?

Take an example where Activity A had called Activity B and when you call finish() on your activity B if finish the activity but as Activity A had given him called and it is a previous activity it returns back you to Activity A screen

> What you can do?

1. You can call [System.exit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) - It will directly kill the application wherever it is called from it does not matter.
2. Use [Process.killProcess](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29)(your process id);
3. Start the home activity by killing your current activity by using  finish() and then call

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```